# convert jQuery to plain javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to replicate the navbar of [this website](http://kompas.com), i have successfully implement it using jQuery but i need to rewrite this in plain javascript

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $nav1 = $("#nav-1"),
        $nav2 = $("#nav-2"),
        $sticky = $nav1.before($nav2.addClass("fixed").removeClass("hide"));

    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("body").toggleClass("on-scroll", (fromTop > 200));
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

this is my attempt to rewrite it in plain JS but its not working atm

```
(function () {
var nav1 = document.getElementById("nav-1"),
    nav2 = document.getElementById("nav-2"),
    sticky = nav1.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", nav2.outerHTML);

// nav2.className += " fixed";
nav2.classList.add("fixed");
nav2.classList.remove("hide");

window.onscroll = function () {
    var fromTop = window.scrollTop;
    body.classList.toggle("on-scroll", fromTop > 200);
};
}());
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: why do you want to write in plain JS instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, first of, you probably want to remove the orginal `#nav-2` since you are making a copy. Second of, you want to determine the scrollTop of the body, which you access by document.body, see updates below:

```
(function () {
var nav1 = document.getElementById("nav-1"),
    nav2 = document.getElementById("nav-2"),
    sticky = nav1.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", nav2.outerHTML);

nav2.parentElement.removeChild(nav2);

// nav2.className += " fixed";
nav2.classList.add("fixed");
nav2.classList.remove("hide");

window.onscroll = function () {
    var fromTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    document.body.classList.toggle("on-scroll", fromTop > 200);
};
}());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ganhammar/jdrjthsq/)